# codeigniter jquery ajax load view page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need when I click anchor tag I need load controller function and get data from  calling function in the model and send it to view_content page and display data

here is my code

**view**

```
<div id="loading"></div>
<a href="" class="company">Click Here</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".company").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var site_url = "<?php echo site_url('site2/home2/'); ?>" +id; //append id at end
    $("#loading").load(site_url);
    //alert(id);
    //alert("aawa");
    });
    });

</script>
```

**controller**

```
 public function home2($id){
        $this->load->model('get_click_data');
        $data['company_data'] = $this->get_click_data->get_company($id);
        $this->load->view('view_content',$data);

    }
```

**model**

```
<?php
class Get_click_data extends CI_Model{

    public function get_company($id){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from companydetails where id = '$id'");
        return $query->result();

    }
```

**view_content**

```
<div id="content">
<h3>Welcome to Home Page 12345</h3>
<?php
    print_r($company_data);
?>
```

Comment: so what is the problem..?

Comment: do not load view_content page,works only alert

Comment: check your console for any errors, your url might not be working as you dont have full url ... and place your alert inside .load()'s callback

Answer (score 3):

as you are using codeigniter, try changing to:

```
...
var id = $(this).attr('id'); //you need to have 'id' attribute in your anchor
$("#loading").load("<?php echo site_url('site2/home2/); ?>" + id, function() {
    alert("aawa");
});
...
```

and in your **controller** file,

```
function some_function($your_id) {
    //get data
    //do something with $your_id
    //pass view as string
    echo $this->load->view('view_content', $data, TRUE);
}
```

**Update::**
to put js variable in your site url, do:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var site_url = "<?php echo site_url('site2/home2/'); ?>" + id; //append id at end
$("#loading").load(site_url, function() {
    alert("aawa");
});
```

**one more update::**
if you want to pass multiple parameters to your function from js, you can do:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var second_param = "some value here";
var site_url = "<?php echo site_url('site2/home2/'); ?>" + id + "/" + second_param;
$("#loading").load(site_url, function() {
    alert("aawa");
});
```

and in your controller function

```
function some_function($your_id, $other_param) {
    do something with $your_id and $other_param
    //pass view as string
    echo $this->load->view('view_content', $data, TRUE);
}
```

**addition::**
in your `home2()` function your are trying to load view, change

```
$this->load->view('view_content',$data);
```

to

```
echo $this->load->view('view_content',$data, TRUE);
```

so that its returned as string to your `.load()` jquery function

Comment: I need to print value of the id inside the site_url

var id = $(this).attr('id');
     $("#loading").load('<?php echo site_url('site2/home2/.+id); ?>');

Comment: @GihanWijethunga see updated answer, you are not passing id properly

Comment: I need to get javascript variable into site_url()
** var id = $(this).attr('id');
     $("#loading").load('<?php echo site_url('site2/home2/.'+id+'.); ?>');**

I need to send id through the variable
@Sudhir

Comment: @GihanWijethunga you can append 'id' to your site_url, and create a js variable and use it in .load() as in updated answer

Comment: then how can I call controller function with a parameter,like u mentioned above

Comment: you can pass in parameters from js like done in site_url above, as site_url + '/' + id1 + '/' + id2, and add arguments to your controller function like function some_function($param1, $param2) { ... }

Comment: @GihanWijethunga in your home2() function your are trying to load view, change to echo $this->load->view('view_content',$data, TRUE); so that its returned as string to your .load() function, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

its working

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".company").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#loading").load('<?php echo site_url('site2/home2/'); ?>'+id);
    alert(id);
    //alert("aawa");
    });
    });
```